# Validate Dobinski's formula using recursive Bell number formula

Tags: recursion

As we know, Bell number can be given using two formula

$B_N=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}C_{N-1}^{k}B_k$ (recursive)

$B_N=e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^N}{k!}$ (Dobinski's  formula)

Now I want to substitute Dobinski's  formula into recursive one to validate it is valid.

Here is what I do

$$
\begin{align}
B_N&=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}C_{N-1}^{k}B_k \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}C_{N-1}^{k}(e^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^k}{i!}) \\
&=e^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i!}(\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}C_{N-1}^{k}i^k) \\
&=e^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(i+1)^{N-1}}{i!} \\
&=e^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(i+1)^N}{(i+1)!} \\
&=e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(k+1)^N}{(k+1)!} \\
?&=e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^N}{k!}
\end{align}
$$

But I have no idea how to deal with the line with a question sign?
Thank you very much!

Comment: In Dobinski's formula, the sum starts from $k=0$.

Comment: @mastrok oh, thank you very much, I will check again.

Comment: What is the value of $\frac{0^N}{0!}$?

Comment: The recursive formula is only valid for $N\gt0.$ If $N\gt0$ then $\frac{0^N}{0!}=\frac01=0.$

Comment: If $N=0$ then Dobinski's formula gives the correct value $B_0=1$.

Comment: thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification given in the comments,
using $$j = k + 1$$ and $$\frac{0^N}{0!}=0$$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
&=e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(k+1)^N}{(k+1)!} \\
&=e^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{j^N}{j!} \\
&=e^{-1}(0 + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{j^N}{j!}) \\
&=e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{j^N}{j!} \\
&=e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^N}{k!} \\
&=B_N
\end{align}
$$